# How to prove that $3x^5-12x^4+21x^3-9x+2$ is irreducible over the rationals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Prove that the polynomial $3x^5-12x^4+21x^3-9x+2$ is irreducible over the rationals

$p=2: f(x)=x^5+x^3+x$..this has root..So this is not irreducible over $Z_2$
so Can I conclude $f(x)$ is irreducible over the rationals?

Comment: Why would you expect that demonstrating a polynomial is *reducible* in one context would imply that it is *irreducible* in a different context?

Answer (score 13):

Try Eisenstein's criterion on $x^5 P(1/x)$.

Comment: Ooh, clever! +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try $p=3$ instead. Remember to appeal to [Gauss's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29#Formal_statements) at some point.

Comment: Using Eisntein's irreducibility Criterion P must not divide $a_n$ and $P^2$ must not divide $a_0$ for $f(x)$ to be irreducible over the field of rational numbers but $a_n=3$ which is divisible by 3. I am trying to figure this out so please do let me know if I am wrong.