# Show that if $a_{0}+a_{1}x+...+a_{n}x^{n}$ is irreducible in K[X] then $a_{n}+a_{n-1}x+...+a_{0}x^{n}$ is also irreducible.

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Let K be a field and let 
$$
f(x) = a_{0}+a_{1}x+...+a_{n}x^{n} 
$$
is irreducible in K[X] then 
$$
a_{n}+a_{n-1}x+...+a_{0}x^{n} 
$$
is also irreducible.

Comment: The answer is an immediate consequence of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/640647/242), so it's essentially a dupe.

Comment: Is there a bijection drawn between the factors of the first and the factors of the second?

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ denotes the first polynomial, then the second is $Q(X) = X^n P(X^{-1})$. Try to use this.