# Is $f(X)=(2+i)X^4+5X^2-3i$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Is $f(X)=(2+i)X^4+5X^2-3i$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

I would be pleased if you could tell me how to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is irreducible. Use the extended Eisenstein again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ Apply Eisenstein to the [reverse ("reciprocal") polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) $\, x^4 f(x^{-1})\,$ using $\,p = 2+i$.

Note that the reversal map $\, f\mapsto  x^d f(x^{-1}),\ d=\deg f\,$ [is *multiplicative*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/640612/242), being the product of two multiplicative maps, namely $\,f(x)\mapsto f(x^{-1}),\,$ and $\,f(x)\mapsto x^{\,\deg f}\ $ (an "exponential" of the *additive* degree map). Being multiplicative, it preserves (ir)reducibility.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and showed with Eisenstein that $x^4*f(x^{-1})$ is irreducible but why is $f(x)$ irreducible?

Comment: @milui I added a note about that.